# Explaining "ground" and grounding as simple as possible

Tags: ground, grounding, circuit-protection

I am a student of electronics, I am also new to it but I am interested in the whole world of electronics. I've managed to get a hang of everything for now without much of a problem. But there is one thing, ground. They never truly explained to us what ground is except a discharge of electricity in real ground. I would like to ask the community to help me out as simple as you can so I can intuitively know what ground is and how it works exactly. Thank you on your time guys!
P.S. I got this problem when learning about a breadboard online and didn't acctualy understanded how do you ground something on a breadboard.

Comment: So much has been written on this subject already. It would be best to explain what you know already - this is not a free-form encyclopedia writing request service...

Comment: *how do you ground something on a breadboard* In general: **you don't**. The only case where that would be needed is if you are building an AM radio and the antenna consists of an antenna wire and a ground connection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of history in the electrical/electronic term ground.  Since you are just starting out, think of it as the reference that all voltages are measured with respect to.  Look at this circuit;

[image]

You could call the node top, bottom, or middle ground.  The circuit will work exactly the same.  If you call bottom ground, all the voltages will be positive.  If you call top ground, all the voltages will be negative.  The voltage across each resistor will, however, not change in polarity or value.  It is just a reference.